# How can I use the '%' wildcard with a LIKE statement in PDO SQL?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have been trying for a while now to get my code to query my MYSQL database for blog post tags, unsucessfully. This is the code in its current form:

```
$tags = explode(", ", $filter);
$insert = "";
foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
    if ($key === 0) {
        $insert .= "where tags like :tag_{$key}";
    }
    else {
        $insert .= " or tags like :tag_{$key}";
    }
}
$query = $inDatabase->prepare("select * from blog_posts
    {$insert} 
    order by :order");
foreach ($tags as $key => $tag) {
    $query->bindParam("tag_{$key}", '%' . $tag . '%');
}
$query->bindParam(":order", $order);
$query->execute();
return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I have tried:

- `$query->bindParam("tag_{$key}", "%$tag%");`
- `$insert .= "where tags like '%' || :tag{$key} || '%'`
- `$insert .= "where tags like %?%";` [...] `$query->bindParam($key, $tag);`

but all with no luck, I keep getting this error: *Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference*, and always ocurrs on the line where the tag parameters are bound to their corresponding variables (e.g., `$query->bindParam("tag_{$key}", '%' . $tag . '%');`).

Any ideas?

Comment: while you've got a response that answers the question, I feel I should also add a note to warn you that `LIKE` queries with a leading wildcard can be *very* slow. The DB has to read through every single record in the table to find matches; that's fine if it's a small set of data, but as your table grows, the speed of your query will drop off badly. If you're expecting to have more than a thousand records or so, you should consider finding an alternative method of searching your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `bindParam` to `bindValue`. That's what error message telling you.